# edit, modify for loops in list comprehension

Tags: python, networkx

I want to create 2 same subgraphs it works when I do it in this manner

```
for _ in range(2):
    for neighbor in graph.adj[i]:
        print(graph.subgraph(neighbor))
```

but when I do it in a list comprehension

```
print([graph.subgraph(neighbor) for neighbor in graph.adj[i] for _ in range(2)])
```

it gives me

```
[<networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x00000156C1587220>, <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x00000156C15873A0>, <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x00000156C15874F0>, <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x00000156C1587640>, <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x00000156C1587790>, <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x00000156C15878E0>]
```

I know about str vs repr but I to make it equivalent to for loops and actually gives an output?

```
Graph with 1 nodes and 0 edges
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your question?

Comment: I tried to edit the Q

Comment: Need more context

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because you have put a pair of square brackets inside the `print` method. Remove them to get it working.

Code:

```
print(graph.subgraph(neighbor) for neighbor in graph.adj[i] for _ in range(2))
```

Hoping an acceptance!

Comment: I tried it before, it's giving a <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001E7380949E0>